# Countdown clicker - JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm totally lost as to where to begin here, how would I create a countdown button so that each time my button is clicked, it prints out the global variable and reduce it by 1 in the innerHTML and when it hits 0 it says BOOM?

I know I have to declare the variable outside but not sure what to do afterwards

JS:

```
var i = 20 

function myFunction()
     {
      i = i--; // the value of i starting at 20
     }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- link to external JS file.  Note that <script> has an
  end </script> tag -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Task 6 </title>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="task6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Create a paragraph with id mydata -->
  <div id="box">
  <p id="mydata"> Count Down  </p>
  <p> <button  onclick="myFunction();"> Click </button></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tryed this code and works fine

```
var i = 20;

function myFunction() {
myData = document.getElementById("mydata");

 i = i - 1;
  myData.textContent = i;

  if(i <= 0) {//with <=0 the user if click again,after zero he sees only BOOM
    myData.textContent = "BOOM!"
  }
}
```

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- link to external JS file.  Note that <script> has an
  end </script> tag -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Task 6 </title>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="task6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Create a paragraph with id mydata -->
  <div id="box">
  <p id="mydata"> Count Down  </p>
  <p> <button  onclick="myFunction();"> Click </button></p>
</div>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- link to external JS file.  Note that <script> has an
  end </script> tag -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Task 6 </title>
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script  type="text/javascript">
  var i = 20;

function myFunction() {
var myData = document.getElementById("mydata");
 
 i = i - 1;
  myData.textContent = i;

  if(i <= 0) {
    myData.textContent = "BOOM!"
  }
}
  
  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Create a paragraph with id mydata -->
  <div id="box">
  <p id="mydata"> Count Down  </p>
  <p> <button  onclick="myFunction();"> Click </button></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to not inline JS in the HTML so I'll provide an extra example to show how to separate it out using a couple of DOM selection methods:

```js
let count = 20;

// grab the element with the mydata id
const mydata = document.getElementById('mydata');

// grab the button and attach an click event listener to it -
// when the button is clicked the `handleClick` function is called
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {
  if (count === 0) {
    mydata.textContent = 'Boom';
  } else {
    mydata.textContent = count;
  }
  count--;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p id="mydata">Countdown</p>  
  <button>Click</button>
  <script src="task6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Reference

- [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: So when I tried adding the code, my INNERHTML block displays 20 but doesnt subtract by 1 even after clicking

Comment: Press F12 and see if any errors are appearing in the developer console.

Comment: I made the code a little simpler to understand with an `if/else` statement instead.

Comment: One last thing: if your code is in `task6.js` move the following line to just before the `</body>`: `<script src="task6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. This way the DOM will load first and then your code can pick up the elements. I've added that to the HTML code in the answer.

Comment: Good one. I think it's also good practice not to use global variables so probably you can handle the count down by getting the current value in "mydata" and subtracting inside the click event. parseInt(document.getElementById("mydata").innerHTML) - 1

Comment: awesome thanks Andy! Im new to JS so looking to learn as much as possible but did work!

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you want to show the variable output and the BOOM at the `<p id="mydata"> Count Down  </p>`, if I am mistaken correct me. So, something like this:

```
let i = 20;
const myData = document.querySelector("#mydata");
function myFunction() {
  i = i - 1;
  myData.textContent = i;

  if(i === 0) {
    myData.textContent = "BOOM!"
  }
}
```

You almost got it whole,only missed the `textContent` and `if` part. If this is what you wanted to achieve. If this isn't what you were looking for, hit me up so I can correct it. Cheers :)

Comment: Im trying to display it in the innerHTML (the countdown box) so that when button is clicked the countdown starts from 20 then click again and goes 19,18,17... ect till 0 and displays BOOM

Comment: Well if you want to change the `innerHTML` of the `<div id="box">... </div>`, by doing so, you will remove the button and you won't be able to click it, because `innerHTML` changes the HTML written in the element. So if you do `document.querySelector("#box").innerHTML = TEXT HERE` it will overwrite the HTML that you have for that `box` element and you will loose the button, thus not being able to click it after the first one.

Answer (score -1):

You need some way of displaying the number inside of your variable.  One of the simplist ways to do this would be to set text to your paragraph tag using getElementById() and inner HTML.  For example, after running your deincrement, on the next line you would do something like...

```
function myFunction()
 {
  i = i--; // the value of i starting at 20
  document.getElementById("mydata").innerHTML = i;
 }
```

This code simply grabs your "mydata" paragraph from the DOM and injects the number into the tag as html.

Comment: No need for `innerHTML` here really. `textContent` would be better.

Comment: I would not say textContent is any better.  innerHTML will let you enter styles and other markup where textContent only allows you to enter plain text.  I think its better to get acquainted with innerHTML, its slightly more robust and with today's browsers has little to know performance difference.

Comment: The question is about adding text to an element - `textContent` is better. And if you're going to add HTML to the DOM these days `insertAdjacentHtml` is preferable to `innerHTML`.